# Facebook Graph API - get full name without using file_get_contents

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't use 'file_get_contents' because my host won't allow php 'open_url_fopen'.

Is there any way of getting the full name of a Facebook user, from their Facebook ID, using PHP without file_get_contents?

(extract the full name from a link like: graph.facebook.com/zuck?ref=ts)

Thanks.

Comment: All facebook api is based on http requests. Can you use other php methods to make http requests? If you can't then you also can not get the user name or other info.

Comment: Does you host allow cURL (http://nl3.php.net/cURL)? That is useable for FB (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the [official Facebook PHP SDK?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Comment: Thanks for the replys,
@scott My host allows cURL, I'm a noob at this, so I don't suppose you could tell me how to use cURL to get the name from Facebook ID?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use cURL

```
$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/zuck?fields=name';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```